# Auto self disappearing message box in Java

Tags: java, messagebox

I would like to create message box with no buttons at all which will disappear for example after 2.5 seconds. I know that I can use `JOptionPana.<method invokation here>` and put in the thread than kill it *but maybe there is  better way*. **If not** how to create empty message box?

Answer (score 1):

Here, there is this example with a `Timer`.
[How to close message dialog programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860731/how-to-close-message-dialog-programmatically)

Comment: Ok so there is no method for disappearing message box. Do you know how to create message box with no buttons?

Comment: Sure :) [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126975/joptionpane-without-button)

Comment: Suppose someone has to sound out all the letters in your message box.  Why not let the user close the box, rather than use a timer?

Comment: Suppose it is one of "those" client "requirements"