# Remove OK Button

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog, titlebar

When the user types the text into the field and presses create. The JFrame title changes to updated user title. The JFrame title variable is in --Window.java-- and the user input is in --NewFileBox.java--. I don't know how you would implement the changes from separate files.

Comment: I'd love to vote up, but I don't have the required repetition.

Comment: You can mark their answers as correct if you are asking questions they answer.

Comment: I just did that on my questions. Thank you for helping me Hovercraft and Cody!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, nfb.inputs, "Create", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);
```

Arg:

*"Create" --> User define title of Dialog Box

Answer (score 0):

**Change title on window.** Okay so as your code stands the only place you can edit the title for your JFrame is inside the Window() Constructor try this.

```
public class Window implements ActionListener{
public String title = "Autumn Engine";
JFrame f;
...
public Window(){
 f = new JFrame(title);
 ...
{
...
}
```

By doing that you can target the `JFrame` anywhere in the Window class allowing you to make adjustments to it where ever. Also it will allow you to target the `JFrame` from the `Window()` ie `window.f.setTitle(title)`

**Remove OK Button** I looked and this question has been asked before here is a link [JOptionPane Without Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126975/joptionpane-without-button)

Comment: I already tried that. For Change title - I would like for the projectName be the "newTitle". As of right now, when it's first opened the title would be blank. Until the user clicks on File -> new, then enters a name and hits create. The title changes to whatever the user input in the field. As of Remove - the only thing I heard of was using JDialog. How would I implement that into my code? I saw examples of JDialog, but still stumped.

Comment: Are you targeting the Window or the JFrame?

Comment: JFrame. I think. It has the title. If not, then the window. I may be mistaken. Excuse me for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Yeah it should be the JFrame that you need to target.

Comment: Then it's the JFrame. Thank you. Anyway to change that? Any ideas? If not, I thank you for the support.

Comment: When are you trying to set the title I don't see it in your code?

Comment: That's the question. I don't know how. I had an initial though, but that didn't work out. I had in --NewFileBox--  on the function (actionPerformed), the code was "name = (projectName.getText());" but that didn't work.

Comment: This looks like a new question. I recommend creating a new question and asking just one question with precise detail on what is happening and what you are wanting to have happen. This question seems to be based around changing the title from an action listener.